# JS function in index.html executed only one time in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I created a small js script which allows me to get pop-up from console message when something will be printed there:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Frontend</title>
  <base href="/">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var exLog = console.log;
      console.log = function(msg) {
        exLog.apply(this, arguments);
        alert(msg);
      }
    })()
    </script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

But function is only executed one time, how to make this every time when something in console occurs?

Comment: Works for me, are you sure you're logging multiple times with no errors?

Comment: It works. Every time you call `console.log` you will get what you want. An alert and a console logging the message.

Comment: Yurgh... Angular app loading jQuery? Nope nope nope...